# Event Value changed in DataTable bound to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, database, datagridview

I have DataTables in a DataSet in a data base bound to a DataGridView. I'd like to show a status if the data changed. So I used the CellValueChanged event of the DataGridView as trigger. In the event routine I check for changes in the DataSet with DataSet.HasChanges if there was really a change. But that is to early, I asume the DataGridView didn't updated the DataTable at that time. From the 2nd change on it works. Is there another event which is fired after updating the data table?

Comment: RowChanged from the DataTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [DataTable.ColumnChanged Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.columnchanged?view=net-6.0), make a change, press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to get original and proposed value. In the following example we first subscribe to the DataTable ColumnChanged event

```
someDataTable.ColumnChanged += ColumnChanged;
```

Then, in this case show values to Visual Studio output window

```
public void ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"       Column name {e.Column.ColumnName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"    Original value [{e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original]}]");
    Console.WriteLine($"    Propose value [{e.ProposedValue}]");
}
```

Or be selective

```
public void ColumnChanged(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (
        e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted || 
        e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Detached || 
        e.Row.RowState == DataRowState.Added) 
        return;

    Console.WriteLine($"       Column name {e.Column.ColumnName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"    Original value [{e.Row[e.Column.ColumnName, DataRowVersion.Original]}]");
    Console.WriteLine($"    Propose value [{e.ProposedValue}]");

}
```